# C# XNA - randomly draw a texture on the top X axis

Tags: c#, random, xna

So I'm making a space invaders game. I want to have meteors spawning from `different/random locations on the entire 0 coordinate of X`. How should I ahieve this? I've seen people using `Lists` and `Random()`s but I need a code for my `meteorGenerator` class. Then I'll call it's methods in Game1

When the meteors are drawn they should fall down at the bottom of the screen and disappear.
I saw an answer here on SO and implemented it to my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;

namespace SpaceInvaders
{
    class meteorGenerator
    {
        public static Vector2 m_Pos;
        public Vector2 m_Position
        {
            get { return m_Pos; }
            set { m_Pos = value; }
        }
        Texture2D m_Texture { get; set; }
        Texture2D m_MeteorsTex;

        public meteorGenerator(Texture2D m_Tex, Vector2 m_Pos)
        {
            m_Position = m_Pos;
            m_Texture = m_Tex;
        }

        List<meteorGenerator> m_MeteorsList = new List<meteorGenerator>();

        static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            m_MeteorsTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\thePlan\\meteorSpawn");
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (m_MeteorsList.Count() < 4)
            {
                m_MeteorsList.Add(new meteorGenerator(m_MeteorsTex, new Vector2(rnd.Next(30, 610), rnd.Next(30, 450))));
            }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            foreach (meteorGenerator m_Meteor in m_MeteorsList)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(m_Meteor.m_Texture, m_Meteor.m_Position, Color.White);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But when I try to instance the constructor of the class in Game1 I get an error:

```
meteorGenerator m_MeteorGenerator;
protected override void Initialize()
{
    // TODO: Add your initialization logic here.
    m_MeteorGenerator = new meteorGenerator(meteorGenerator.m_Tex, meteorGenerator.m_Pos);
}
```

`Error  1   'SpaceInvaders.meteorGenerator' does not contain a definition for 'm_Tex'`

Comment: This is too broad for SO. If you have a *specific* question about the technology, or some code you have; please narrow this question down to it.

Comment: What I need is an approach/guide to follow and implement into my game. I don't have any code in my meteorGenerator class yet, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Okay; but you say you've seen code using `List` and `Random`. That is indeed the right approach. What was confusing about it to you? *That* question is what you should be asking here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET OK, I edited my question. Can I have an review of the code and what is wrong?

Comment: Why are you naming arguments with `m_` prefixes such as in `public meteorGenerator(Texture2D m_Tex, Vector2 m_Pos)` - that's very confusing and bad practice

Comment: Oh, just a habbit from the C++ Hungarian notation... Any other thoughts on my code?

Comment: @Charlie I meant in your **function definition** _not_ when you go to _invoke it_.  That's not Hungarian notation anyway.

Comment: Should `meteorGenerator.m_Tex` read `meteorGenerator.m_Texture` but then you would have to define it as static?  But then that would only make sense if you wanted to share the same texture in which case you would probably rewrite your code so that you don't pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: You are invoking a constructor and trying to pass it *its own texture*. The whole thing doesn't make sense; just get rid of the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick.

I renamed the parameters for the constructor to vTexture and vPos but I agree with the comments this is old style coding and very confusing. Now we would use

```
 public Vector2 position
 public Vector2 Position
 {
   get { return position }
   set { position = value; }
 }

public meteorGenerator(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position)
{
    Position = texture;
    Texture = position;
}
```

But that is splitting hairs for now.

What I did change is m_MeteorsList, LoadContent, Update and Draw are now static.

you can just call

```
meteorGenerator.Loadcontent(Content) // to load your content
meteorGenerator.Update(gameTime) // will generate the meteors
meteorGenerator.Draw(spriteBatch) // will draw them.
```

No need to have multiple instances of the meteorGenerator class.

I honestly don't think this good practice as I would have used a separate Meteor class or struct to store information about meteors.

```
namespace SpaceInvaders
{
  class meteorGenerator
  {
    public Vector2 m_Pos;
    public Vector2 m_Position
    {
        get { return m_Pos; }
        set { m_Pos = value; }
    }
    Texture2D m_Texture { get; set; }
    Texture2D m_MeteorsTex;

    public meteorGenerator(Texture2D vTex, Vector2 vPos)
    {
        m_Position = vPos;
        m_Texture = vTex;
    }

    static List<meteorGenerator> m_MeteorsList = new List<meteorGenerator>();

    static readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public static void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        m_MeteorsTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\thePlan\\meteorSpawn");
    }

    public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (m_MeteorsList.Count() < 4)
        {
            m_MeteorsList.Add(new meteorGenerator(m_MeteorsTex, new Vector2(rnd.Next(30, 610), rnd.Next(30, 450))));
        }
    }

    public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        foreach (meteorGenerator m_Meteor in m_MeteorsList)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(m_Meteor.m_Texture, m_Meteor.m_Position, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

}